# Converting already opened XLS to CSV

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I have VBscript code which opens XLS file and export it to CSV, see below:

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("test.xls")
oBook.SaveAs "test.csv", 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

It works fine but I need to do the same - convert XLS to CSV with already opened file "test.xls" on my computer which is different (edited by me) versus saved version. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just need to connect the existing instance of Excel and set workbook object variable equal to the already open workbook instead:

```
Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks("test.xls")
```

Comment: Thank you for so fast respond! Works perfectly!